# node js Uncaught Error: error with HTTP module

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

i am new to nodejs and this probleme made a headeach for me
This is my code below:

```
import http from 'http';
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

The Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving 'http' module specifier. Relative module specifiers must start with "./", "../" or "/"
```

I searched in blogs and youtube and I couldn't find the answer(Note: just three days ago this code worked perfectly but now it shows me this error).

Hope someone can help me to fix this Error.

Comment: how are you running this and what does the structure of your project look like?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to run this in a browser or some environment other than nodejs.  This is nodejs code meant to be run in nodejs.